# Bootstrap-Table loading data

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-table

I got difficulties in bootstrap table data loading:

Currently in my `.js`, i defined as this:

```
var data = '[{"id": 0,"name": "Item 0","price": "$0"}, {"id": 1,"name": "Item 1","price": "$1"},{"id": 2,"name": "Item 2","price": "$2"}]';
```

I used 2 methods of loading the data to the table:

1. JSON parse above data

   ```
   blabla=JSON.parse(data);
   $('#table').bootstrapTable('load',blabla);
   ```

   this feature is working fine
2. use the data:

   ```
   var blabla=JSON.parse(data);
   $('#table').bootstrapTable({
       data: blabla
   });
   ```

Could anyone enlighten me, why 2nd option couldnt view the data table?
And how should the syntax for 2nd option look like if its wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue a while ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014498/bootstrap-table-update-content-not-working) and ended up using 'load' .. also interested in, why 'data' isnt working

Comment: Odd. Based on the [documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) the syntax for 2. is correct. And the second example on their [examples page](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/) uses that syntax and works.

Comment: from the documentation,  
  it is shown that for data:  data - Array [] The data to be loaded.  please note that variable blabla is a parsed JSON data, will this cause the issue?